# Installing Enclosure with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, clojure, enclojure

I am having trouble installing Enclosure and getting it to work.  I have followed this guide http://www.enclojure.org/gettingstarted and successfully installed Enclosure (I think).  However, when I try to build the sample application (labrepl) I get a bunch of errors and a failed build.  I haven't used Java in a long time and I've never used Netbeans, and the error doesn't seem very helpful with my limited knowledge of this domain.  I'm using the latest Netbeans and the Enclosure URL from the guide.  Since I am on Windows, I can't use git to clone the repo, so I'm not sure what to do from here.

Anyway, here are the error messages.

```
WARNING: You are running embedded Maven builds, some build may fail due to incompatibilities with latest Maven release.
         To set Maven instance to use for building, click here.
Scanning for projects...
[#process-resources]
[resources:resources]
Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[#compile]
[ERROR]Transitive dependency resolution for scope: compile has failed for your project.
[ERROR]Error message: Missing:
[ERROR]----------
[ERROR]1) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]  Then, install it using the command: 
[ERROR]      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR]  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
[ERROR]      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.clojure -DartifactId=clojure-contrib -Dversion=1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR]  Path to dependency: 
[ERROR]          1) labrepl:labrepl:jar:0.0.1
[ERROR]          2) org.clojure:clojure-contrib:jar:1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]----------
[ERROR]1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR]for artifact: 
[ERROR]  labrepl:labrepl:jar:0.0.1
[ERROR]from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
[ERROR]  clojars (http://clojars.org/repo/),
[ERROR]  incanter (http://repo.incanter.org),
[ERROR]  clojure-snapshots (http://build.clojure.org/snapshots),
[ERROR]  clojure (http://build.clojure.org/releases),
[ERROR]  clojure-releases (http://build.clojure.org/releases)
[ERROR]Group-Id: labrepl
[ERROR]Artifact-Id: labrepl
[ERROR]Version: 0.0.1
[ERROR]From file: C:\Users\chloey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RelevanceLabRepl\pom.xml
------------------------------------------------------------------------
For more information, run with the -e flag
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILED
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1 second
Finished at: Wed Jun 09 21:53:04 CDT 2010
Final Memory: 72M/172M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks all.

Comment: The correct spelling is "Enclojure", not "Enclosure". I have no rights to edit this by myself.

Answer (score 0):

the missing artifact is the artifact itself. What command are you using to build it? Try `mvn clean install` on the command line if everything else fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I did a clean install of Netbeans followed by and install of maven both to no avail.

When I went to download the missing artifact I noticed that clojure-contrib version 1.2.0 was not available for download.  Changing the pom.xml to look for version 1.1.0 resulted in a successful build.

Open the pom.xml and change

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
  <artifactId>clojure-contrib</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
  <artifactId>clojure-contrib</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0-master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

By the looks of things some additional functionality within 1.2.0 is needed for labrepl not sure from where to download it.